# For a continuous (or even differentiable) function $f$ on $[a,b]$, if $f$ is not monotonic, is there always an extremal point lies in $(a,b)$?

Tags: calculus

For a continuous (or even differentiable) function $f$ on $[a,b]$, if $f$ is not monotonic, is there always a local extremal point which lies in $(a,b)$?

Comment: No consider $f(x)=x^3-2x+3$ on $(5,5)$ it has extrema only at the endpoints of the interval

Comment: @DominicPetti on $(5,5)=\emptyset$? Do you mean $(-5,5)$?

Comment: On $[5,5]$ sorry, I’m assuming global extrema but if not I’m unsure

Comment: @DominicPetti The example you show is too special!

Comment: Well assuming "extremal points" are absolute extrema, then the function $f$ as in @DominicPetti 's comment on $[-5,5]$ is not monotonic and never achieves an absolute max nor an absolute min.

Comment: are we talking about local or global extrema ?

Comment: @nicomezi local extema

Answer (score 1):

Because $f$ is continuous and not monotonic there exists a sub-interval $[a',b'] \subset (a,b)$ with $f(a') = f(b')$

And $f$ is continuous on $[a',b']$ so the maximum value M and minimum value m  are attained and at least one of them is a local extremum then.

If $m=M$ the function $f$ is constant on $[a',b']$ hence all points within the interval are local extrema.

If $m \not= M$ then because of $f(a') = f(b')$ at least one of them is a local extremum.

Comment: Absolutely right! Thanks very much!